# How to unset a specific php session on logout

Tags: php, session, logout

I have 2 sites.

In one site this is true:

```
session_is_registered('site1sess')
```

and in the other one this is true:

```
session_is_registered('site2sess')
```

Those are the session names I give users on login. My problem is that when I logout from one site, I also logout in the other one because I use:

```
session_destroy();
```

What is the best way to logout from site1 or 2 deleting all the session variables from it?
Thank you.

Comment: $_SESSION['site2sess']=null should do it

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['session_var']);`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `unset()` for all the session variables specific to either site 1 or 2.

```
unset($_SESSION['site1']);
//or
unset($_SESSION['site2']);
```

Just so that you know, `session_is_registered` is deprecated as of PHP version 5.3.0. [See docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php).

Comment: Isn't it `session_unset($_SESSION['site1']);` Can't find `unset();`

Comment: `session_unset()` will unset ALL session variables.

Answer (score 2):

Before `unset($_SESSION['site1']);` put `session_start()` like this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['site1']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you log out of 1

```
unset($_SESSION['site1sess']);
```

Or when you log out of the other

```
unset($_SESSION['site2sess']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset session while you don't want to logout logged in user.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
   session_unset($_SESSION['user']);
}
```

Comment: `session_unset()` does not accept any arguments - it unsets ALL variables in the current `$_SESSION`. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php).