# how to logout admin or user php

Tags: php, html, session

I have two login forms, for user and admin.

When the User or Admin Login, I have set `$_SESSION['login'] = true` for user;
`$_SESSION['loginadmin'] = true` for admin.I want to logout from page admin to use `session_destroy` and page user is logout too,

What could I do to logout admin and let user stay logged in

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unset a specific php session on logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455965/how-to-unset-a-specific-php-session-on-logout)

Comment: read about unset : http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Don't destroy the session - you need it for your user info, still. Just set loginadmin to false: `$_SESSION['loginadmin'] = false;`

Comment: Seconded @JohnConde. There a couple of good practices that Stackers could help you, but without trying the basics and searching better it's impossible, go to www.php.net and use google + previous stack questions!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set admin value to `false`

```
$_SESSION['loginadmin'] = false;
```

or you can `unset` admin variable only

```
unset($_SESSION['loginadmin']);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @Chando u need to accept answers that helped solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

## Creating New Session

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
?>
```

## Getting Session

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*session created*/
echo $_SESSION["newsession"];
/*session was getting*/
?>
```

## Updating Session

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  
global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*it is my new session*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$updatedvalue;
/*session updated*/
?>
```

## Deleting Session

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  
global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
unset($_SESSION["newsession"]);
/*session deleted. if you try using this you've got an error*/
?>
```

Check Out:
  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

They have good information to fall back on and search for queries.